# not able to extract variables from given sample

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a sample string from which i have to extract values.
Given Sample:

```
    {#-- important parameters #}
    {#@@ { 'var1': { 'title':'blah blah', 'type':'text', 'value':'def. text', 'maxlength':10 },
           'var2': { 'title':'blah blah', 'type':'number', 'value':10, 'min':1, 'max':100 } } #}
    {#@@ { 'var3': { 'title':'blah blah', 'type':'range', 'value':'3.0', 'min':1, 'max':10, step: '0.1' } } #}
    {#-- normal parameters #}
    {#@@ { 'var4': { 'title':'blah blah', 'type':'text', 'value':'def. text', 'required':'false' } } #}

{{Variable_1}}
{{Variable_2}}
{{Variable_3}}
```

I want to extract them as given below:

1 ) {#-- important parameters #} to "important parameters" - Regex which will only extract from this {#-- #}

2)

```
{#@@ { 'var1': { 'title':'blah blah', 'type':'text', 'value':'def. text', 'maxlength':10 },
       'var2': { 'title':'blah blah', 'type':'number', 'value':10, 'min':1, 'max':100 } } #} to  { 'var1': { 'title':'blah blah', 'type':'text', 'value':'def. text', 'maxlength':10 },
       'var2': { 'title':'blah blah', 'type':'number', 'value':10, 'min':1, 'max':100 } }
```

--- regex which will only extract from this {#@@  #}

currently using :

1. `/[^{\#\-]+(?=#\})/g` for these templates {#-- normal parameters #} --- it is extracting values from both patterns i need to parse one pattern at a time.
2. `/[^#@@]+(?=#\})/g` for these templates

   {#@@ { 'var1': { 'title':'blah blah', 'type':'text', 'value':'def. text', 'maxlength':10 },
   'var2': { 'title':'blah blah', 'type':'number', 'value':10, 'min':1, 'max':100 } } #}

--- it is extracting values from both patterns i need to parse one pattern at a time

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A regex isn't able to dynamically parse a character string. Let me explain: it's not possible to capture a dynamically variable number of groups.

However, this regex can match the "title" group and the first "parameters" group:

```
/ {#--\s+(.*?)\s+#}\s+?{#@@\s+((?:.|\n)+?)\s+#} /gm
```

If you wan to match all `{#@@ XXX #}`groups, you must know in advance the maximum number of possible cases. IT can be done with a regex like this (in case of max two parameters):

```
/ {#--\s+(.*?)\s+#}\s+?{#@@\s+((?:.|\n)+?)\s+#}(?:\s+?{#@@\s+((?:.|\n)+?)\s+#})? /gm
```

Otherwise, you must do it in two steps:

- capturing all `{#@@ XXX #}` by `{#-- XXX #}` in a global group
- spliting this group by `{#@@ XXX #}` parts.

---

For further explanation, the first regex shown above can be splitted into two parts:

- `{#--\s+(.*?)\s+#}` for capturing `{#-- XXX #}` in the `group(1)`
- `{#@@\s+((?:.|\n)+?)\s+#}` for capturing `{#@@ XXX #}` in the `group(2)`

Comment: You can use RegExp(`${var}`. ) // just be sure to double escape special characters because its in a string format instead of regex format